# using redis in place of a database on heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis

I have a simple app deployed on heroku.  Basically users come and type in search terms.  I would like to add a little section on the side of the page that shows 'recent searches'.  Though just for this I don't want to add a database to my application.  I've read about redis but is this something it could be used for? can I just push about 10 recent search terms on the redis hash and retrieve them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is a good use case for redis. Push the search terms on a Redis list, and retrieve the last ten when you want to display them. Periodically you can remove all but the ten last items from the list to avoid it getting too large.

Add items to the list like this (assuming `REDIS` is a Redis connection):

```
REDIS.rpush('searches', 'Xyz')
```

and retrieve the last ten like this:

```
REDIS.lrange('searches', -10, -1)
```

(as a side effect Redis will get the last element of the list first, which is probably what you want). Redis lists work like Ruby arrays, negative indices means counting from the end.

To cap the list to ten elements you can use this command:

```
REDIS.ltrim('searches', -10, -1)
```

either you do this every time you push something, to make sure the list never grows, or you do it periodically. The `lrange` operation means that you will only ever retrieve the last 10 elements anyway, so it's just a matter of preference.